# 'ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name' equivalent for remote json

Tags: python, json, python-requests, google-authentication, gspread

I'm setting up a program to help the user with their notes for a research paper, and I'm at the point where i need to separate the `client_secret.json` from the program files to keep it secure online. How do I get the creds from the json without having it as a file with the python program?

```
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
gs = gspread.authorize(creds)
```

In the code above, is there some way I can use the json response rather than the client_secret.json file something more like :

```
creds = requests.get("json storage").json
```

Answer (score 15):

The best would be to create the keys of your secret JSON as environment variables, and have a function that returns a dict in the same format of the json that you can then use with the auth method [from_json_keyfile_dict](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html#oauth2client.service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict)

This is how I do it, and how I call my environment variables:

```py
def create_keyfile_dict():
    variables_keys = {
        "type": os.environ.get("SHEET_TYPE"),
        "project_id": os.environ.get("SHEET_PROJECT_ID"),
        "private_key_id": os.environ.get("SHEET_PRIVATE_KEY_ID"),
        "private_key": os.environ.get("SHEET_PRIVATE_KEY"),
        "client_email": os.environ.get("SHEET_CLIENT_EMAIL"),
        "client_id": os.environ.get("SHEET_CLIENT_ID"),
        "auth_uri": os.environ.get("SHEET_AUTH_URI"),
        "token_uri": os.environ.get("SHEET_TOKEN_URI"),
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": os.environ.get("SHEET_AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL"),
        "client_x509_cert_url": os.environ.get("SHEET_CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL")
    }
    return variables_keys

# then the following should work

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(create_keyfile_dict(), scope)
gs = gspread.authorize(creds)
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer from Philippe is correct, but it didn't quite work for me.

I had to change `create_keyfile_dict` method, adding `.replace("\\n", "\n")` to the `private_key`.

This is my final result:

```
def create_keyfile_dict():
    variables_keys = {
        "type": os.environ.get("SHEET_TYPE"),
        "project_id": os.environ.get("SHEET_PROJECT_ID"),
        "private_key_id": os.environ.get("SHEET_PRIVATE_KEY_ID"),
        "private_key": os.environ.get("SHEET_PRIVATE_KEY").replace("\\n", "\n"),
        "client_email": os.environ.get("SHEET_CLIENT_EMAIL"),
        "client_id": os.environ.get("SHEET_CLIENT_ID"),
        "auth_uri": os.environ.get("SHEET_AUTH_URI"),
        "token_uri": os.environ.get("SHEET_TOKEN_URI"),
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": os.environ.get("SHEET_AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL"),
        "client_x509_cert_url": os.environ.get("SHEET_CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL"),
    }
    return variables_keys

# Google Sheet credentials
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(
    create_keyfile_dict(),
    ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"],
)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

Comment: well damn, I'm glad this was useful to you 4 years later. Happy coding!

Comment: I needed this change, too. So thank you! It worked for me.